# How to combine two arrays into the one, alternating elements?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose you have array arr[N] of increasing numbers. You have to divide it in two other (Left and Right):

```
L = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...}

R = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...}
```

The following algorithm does this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < (N / 2) ; i++ )
    {
        L[i] = arr[2 * i + 0];
        R[i] = arr[2 * i + 1];
    }
```

The question is: **How to do the reverse algorithm?**

So the output array will be:

```
arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...}
```

**P.S.**
I've been thinking a lot about it but with no rezult :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original problem doesn't specify whether or not the original array is guaranteed to have an even number of elements.

If this is not the case 
your solution nor

```
 for (i = 0; i < (N / 2); i++) {
     arr[2 * i + 0] = L[i];
     arr[2 * i + 1] = R[i]; }
```

are guaranteed to work.

The safest bet would be

```
LR = {L, R};

for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
    LR[i mod 2][i/2] = arr[i];
}
```

as is posted above.

Comment: I like the above solution but just askin':
Is there any faster and/or bultin .NET way to do the alternating merge?

Answer (score 10):

The easy solution is just to literally reverse your existing operation:

```
for (i = 0; i < (N / 2); i++)
{
    arr[2 * i + 0] = L[i];
    arr[2 * i + 1] = R[i];
}
```